# Pattern for people relations

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Consider the following code.  I'm trying to figure out a proper pattern and this is the best I can think of so far.  The strange part is the transition from storing "people seen" to "people known".  I had to choose an arbitrary metric that once you seen someone too many times (say, 100 times), you should no longer keep track of how many times you've seen that person and consider him to be someone you know (or at least am familiar with).  I pondered over whether to use Observer Pattern, or Publish and Subscribe, and went with neither and just did the following and am wonder if there may be a better way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

enum SightingOccasion { SawRandomly, InSameProtest, InSameChurch };
enum RelationType { Friend, Enemy, SeenManyTimes }; 
// SeenManyTimes is the hot topic.  In this program, if someone has been seen over 100 times, he
// shall be transferred from Person::peopleSeen to Person::peopleKnown.  Seems sound enough?

struct Sighting {
//  Date date;  // Remeoved to keep this simple
    SightingOccasion sightingOccasion;
};

struct Relation {
    RelationType relationType;
    int closenessValue;  // Ranges from -100 to 100.
};

class Person {
    std::string name;
    std::map<Person*, std::vector<Sighting>> peopleSeen;
    std::map<Person*, Relation> peopleKnown;
public:
    Person (const std::string& n) : name(n) { }
    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    void addToPeopleSeen (Person* person, SightingOccasion s);
    void addToPeopleKnown (Person* person, RelationType r, int c) { peopleKnown[person] = {r, c}; }
    void transferFromSeenToKnown (Person* person, RelationType r = SeenManyTimes, int c = 0) { peopleSeen.erase(person);   addToPeopleKnown(person, r, c); }
    void adjustClosenessValue (Person* person, int n) { peopleKnown.at(person).closenessValue += n; }
};

void Person::addToPeopleSeen (Person* person, SightingOccasion s) {
    if (peopleKnown.find(person) != peopleKnown.end()) {
        std::cout << person->getName() << " is already known to " << getName() << " so will not be added to his peopleSeen.\n";
        adjustClosenessValue(person, 1);  // The '1' should be some function of 's' and whatever happened during the SightingOccasion.
        return;
    }   
    peopleSeen[person].push_back({s});
    if (peopleSeen[person].size() > 100) {
        std::cout << getName() << " has seen " << person->getName() << " over 100 times.  Will transfer " << person->getName() << " to peopleKnown with RelationType SeenManyTimes.\n";
        transferFromSeenToKnown(person);
    }
}

int main() {
    Person *sam = new Person("Sam"), *mark = new Person("Mark"), *tom = new Person("Tom");
    sam->addToPeopleKnown(mark, Friend, 85);
    mark->addToPeopleKnown(sam, Friend, 78);
    for (int i = 0;  i < 100;  ++i)
        sam->addToPeopleSeen(tom, SawRandomly);
    std::vector<Person*> protestors = { sam, mark, tom };  // and many other people, and they have all seen each other.
    for (Person* p : protestors) {
        for (Person* q : protestors) {
            if (p == q) continue;   
                p->addToPeopleSeen(q, InSameProtest);
        }
    }
    
}

/*
Output:

Mark is already known to Sam so will not be added to his peopleSeen.
Sam has seen Tom over 100 times.  Will transfer Tom to peopleKnown with RelationType SeenManyTimes.
Sam is already known to Mark so will not be added to his peopleSeen.
*/
```

Comment: Is struct Sighting really necesary after date is removed?

Comment: @ convert  Just a wrapper class for future developments (e.g. `int impression;` will be added on top of Date, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using `std::string`, but failed to include the `<string>` header.

Prefer `enum class` when the numeric values aren't significant.

These are problematic:

> ```
> std::map<Person*, std::vector<Sighting>> peopleSeen;
> std::map<Person*, Relation> peopleKnown;
> ```

It's not valid to compare pointers that don't point within the same object, so `std::map` is not a suitable container for these.  Check whether we can use a `std::unordered_map` instead (I really can't remember right now).

It might be a good idea to map from a `std::reference_wrapper<Person>` so that we're clear that the map never contains a `nullptr` entry.

The constant `100` is a *policy* choice, so give it a name and declare it somewhere visible rather than in the internals of `addToPeopleSeen()`.

Sorry for lightning review - busy day today!